# PHP - Problem using file_get_contents

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have a problem while using the file_get_contents function. I am using it to get a response from a different web server, but it's not returning anything (shown as empty string using var_dump). Also, the problem is only while calling this specific server, because I got result when I used Google's address; and it's working fine in my local machine.
I've tried cUrl too - but same result.

Comment: Please provide the response from `get_headers($theURL)` and make sure you got `error_reporting(-1)` enabled. Click the `edit` link below your question to add the details.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do:

```
echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
```

If this is false, you should try setting it to true in your php.ini before calling file_get_contents.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set the user agent? Some sites may check this and disallow bots.

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Name of your bot');
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be issue with the server you are calling is the file with the appropriate permissions and is it accessible from a normal web browser? If the file access is restricted by IP is your  server'sIP allowed?